# Align date to right side

Tags: html, zope

Trying To Align date next to the hyper link .Even though added align="right" it still shows in left

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/page_white_acrobat_small.png" style="margin-right: 0.3rem;" align="absbottom" />
        <a style="font-size: 12px" href = ""  onclick="Popup.open({url:'PERTI_Plan.pdf',width:800,height:500,resizable:'yes', separateWindow:true});">FAA/ATC NEXT DAY PLAN <label tal:content="string: ${pertiDate}" style="margin-right: 0.3rem;" align="right"  >
        </label>
        </a> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image: DATE]

Comment: @Eystein Bye iavery's solution is working just I am trying to reduce the distance between the   FAA/ATC NEXT DAY PLAN  and the date now it goes in extreme right

Comment: Why the question is downvoted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your style tag to `style="margin-right: 0.3rem; display:block; float: right;"`

Comment: Should we really be encouraging inline CSS :P

Comment: Lol. OK, good point. Try adding `class="right-link"` or some such to that <a> tag, and then add the following inside your style sheet or a <style> tag:
`.right-link { margin-right: 0.3rem; display :block; float: right; }`

Comment: looking for inline css that would be helpful

Comment: @HariomSingh Have you tried adding the style "float: left" to the <img> element?

Comment: Worked but date comes too right with lot of spaces in between

Comment: @ iavery did some more modification of your solution and it works

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your CSS called pull-right..

```
.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
```

...and then add that class to your element.

```
class="pull-right"
```

Comment: Inline css will be helpful

Comment: Inline CSS is bad generally.. although inline would just be the same styles but on a style="float: right;" attribute.